# Haskell function with optional return value

Tags: haskell

I have created type `Transition` which is a tuple like `(int q1, char s, int q2)` and type `T` that is array of `Transition`s. I need a function that will return `q2` that matches our `q1` and `s`, and `-1` if we dont have such transition. I wrote a function `delta`, but the problem is that it returns list.

```
type Transition q = (q, Char, q) 
type T q = [Transition q]

delta :: (Eq a) => FSM a -> Char -> a -> [a] 
delta m symbol st = [q1 | (q0, x, q1) <- trans m, q0 == st, x == symbol ]
```

Comment: so you are asking how to get the first thing from a list or -1 if it's empty?

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) type. You have to change the type signature to:

```
delta :: (Eq a) => FSM a -> Char -> a -> Maybe[a]
```

Then  you have to return `Just q2` if there is a result and `Nothing` otherwise.